# Selenium WebDriver : <option> could not be scrolled into view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to do a bot to navigate a website with Python and Selenium Webdriver but I found a trouble when trying to access and change the result_delimiter of some data returned by the site. They have "comma" as default delimiter and I need they to be separate by "New Line"

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<select id="result_delimiter">
                <option value="comma" selected="selected">Comma</option>
                <option value="new_line">New Line</option>
                <option value="space">Space</option>
                <option value="vertical_bar">Vertical Bar</option>
            </select>
```

And the error it is returning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...xxx\AsinGrabberTest.py", line 28, in <module>
    select.click()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <option> could not be scrolled into view
```

I know I could download my data with commas and then make the change within the program, **BUT** I'm unavailable to access to the text Area when the results are showed and copy them. Following, the HTML related to this text area:

```
<textarea class="asin-holder-big" id="result_list"></textarea>
```

I would thank any solution, to could select the "new_line" option or to could copy the information provided in the text area.

Below, the code used:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from pruebaAmazon import copy_link
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://arkgroup.org/asin-grabber/about/')
currentURL = ('https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bd57_wht_21023130?ref=nav_cs_gb&gb_f_deals1=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL%252CEXPIRED%252CSOLDOUT%252CUPCOMING,includedAccessTypes:,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,enforcedCategories:2102313011&pf_rd_p=8cc92576-e249-4c23-a4f8-4720526dbd57&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=AEPDZ9VY9XE3B2FX3W95&ie=UTF8')

def paste_link():
    URL.click()
    URL.send_keys(currentURL)


login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/section/ul[1]/li[2]/a").click()
name = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/form/input[1]").send_keys('xxx@gmail.com')
password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/form/input[2]').send_keys('xxx')
submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/form/button').click()
goButton= browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/a').click()
fetchA = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
URL = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="path"]')
#paste_link()
URL.click()
URL.send_keys(currentURL)

fetchButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="get_asins"]').click()
select = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.no-websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.no-cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.no-applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths body div#Results.reveal-modal.open div.row div.large-6.columns select#result_delimiter option")
select.click()
```

and the other .py file called "PruebaAmazon"

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Firefox()           #Sets Firefox as default browser               
browser.get("https://www.amazon.com/")  #Opens amazon page


def copy_link():
    currentURL = browser.current_url
    #print(currentURL)
    return currentURL


login = browser.find_element_by_id('nav-link-accountList').click()
mail = browser.find_element_by_id("ap_email").send_keys('xxx@gmail.com')
continuar = browser.find_element_by_id("continue").click()
password = browser.find_element_by_id("ap_password").send_keys('xxx')
rememberMe = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/label/div/label/input").click()
signInSubmit = browser.find_element_by_id("signInSubmit").click()
todayDeals = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[3]').click();
checkBox = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/div/label/input').click()

browser.quit()
```

Comment: can you please share the code you have tried

Comment: Ok, it's kind complicated because I have personal credentials that I had to use, but I'll put "xxx" instead within the code.

Comment: That is not an issue

Comment: I've already edited the post

Comment: first of all I think you should fix the selectors: with such selectors your code is unreadable, and nobody - not even you - can say if that node selection is correct. Meanwhile your select has ID, so just do this: `select = browser.find_element_by_id("result_delimiter")`. Second, since `URL.send_keys(currentURL)` probably dynamically changes the page, you may need to *wait* for select to appear, e.g.: `select = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'result_delimiter'))`.

Comment: finally use `Select` oject you already imported to select an option, rather than selecting it directly: `Select(select).select_by_visible_text("New Line")`

Comment: Thanks Kiril, but what do you mean with  "unreadable selectors"? How do you think should them be? with id's instead of xpath's?   I also tried your solutions, but it returns the following error:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xx.py", line 32, in <module>
    select = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, 'result_delimiter'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: You need to import EC as well `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`.

Comment: For selectors: yes, they should be logical and minimal. That way they have less chance to fail due to minimal page changes, they are more readable (it's much easier to verify that element with specific ID exists, than some complicated path), they make sense, and on top of that efficiency of the selectors goes from ID (most efficient) to xpath of type `//*[condition]` (least efficient). So if you have non-dynamic ID - yes, best to use it directly, with nothing else. If you don't, choose minimal unique path to element, not the entire path from the root.

Comment: oh, and using elements by index, e.g. `div[8]` is especially bad, since if anything changes on the page (e.g. some ad had another div in it, and it changed the indexing), it will break, but you won't even know what you meant by that element. Always use some properties of the element, never use index.

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks a lot, but I still have the same problem, it's not because a lack of EC importation. :(